# How to set the max size of upload file

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm developing application based on Spring Boot and AngularJS using JHipster.
My question is how to set **max size of uploading files**?

If I'm trying to upload to big file I'm getting this information in console:

```
  DEBUG 11768 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.a.app.aop.logging.LoggingAspect: 

Enter: com.anuglarspring.app.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.processRuntimeException() with argument[s] = 

[org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.]
```

And server response with status 500.

How to set that?

Answer (score 250):

Also in Spring boot **1.4**, you can add following lines to your application.properties to set the file size limit:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128KB
```

for spring boot **2.x** and above its

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Worked for me. Source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

**UPDATE:**

Somebody asked the differences between the two properties.

Below are the formal definitions:

> MaxFileSize: The maximum size allowed for uploaded files, in bytes. If the size of any uploaded file is greater than this size, the web container will throw an exception (IllegalStateException). The default size is unlimited.
>
> MaxRequestSize: The maximum size allowed for a multipart/form-data request, in bytes. The web container will throw an exception if the overall size of all uploaded files exceeds this threshold. The default size is unlimited.

To explain each:

MaxFileSize: **The limit for a single file to upload**. This is applied for the single file limit only.

MaxRequestSize: **The limit for the total size of all files in a single upload request**. This checks the total limit. Let's say you have two files *a.txt* and *b.txt* for a single upload request. *a.txt* is *5kb* and *b.txt* is *7kb* so the `MaxRequestSize` should be above *12kb*.

Comment: I used the below in spring boot 2.0.1

`spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size = 5MB`

Comment: What is the difference between `max-file-size` and `max-request-size`?

Comment: `max-file-size` --> maximum size for a single file to upload. `max-request-size` --> the limit for the total size of the all files in a single upload request. So; if you want to increase the upload size, you have to increase both values because one is for a single file limit and one is for the total size of the all files in a single request.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot for microservice development, you have to add the same config to the gateway service to prevent upload errors. I hope it saves someone the troubles I went through

Comment: As @AguThadeus suggested for microservice development with a gateway setup, we need to add the `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 5MB spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size = 5MB` in the gateway properties as-well

Comment: I don't know why but if I use spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=50MB this not works... with value < 50MB it's ok. Any open issues?

Answer (score 34):

For Spring Boot 2.+, make sure you are using `spring.servlet` instead of `spring.http`.

```
---
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
```

If you have to use tomcat, you might end up creating [EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer](https://gist.github.com/dalesupa22/2b5f67afd7a8b3a39714), which is not really nice thing to do.

If you can live without tomat, you could [replace tomcat with e.g. undertow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-undertow-instead-of-tomcat) and avoid this issue at all.

Comment: change of spring.servlet has been introduced in spring boot 2+, worth to edit your answer as previously it was (spring boot <= 1.5.9) spring.http.multipart

Comment: or: 
`spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB`

`spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB`

Comment: Concurring #SWiggels. Using spring.servlet... for those who running version > 1.5.9.

Answer (score 33):

In Spring Boot 2 the `spring.http.multipart` changed to `spring.servlet.multipart`

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M1-Release-Notes#multipart-configuration

Comment: bless you sir!!

Comment: u saved my day !

Comment: What prompted Pivotal guys to do this change ? I feel this could be overhead for spring boot upgrade to Spring Boot 2.

Answer (score 25):

You need to set the `multipart.maxFileSize` and `multipart.maxRequestSize` parameters to higher values than the default. This can be done in your spring boot configuration yml files. For example, adding the following to `application.yml` will allow users to upload 10Mb files:

```
multipart:
    maxFileSize: 10Mb
    maxRequestSize: 10Mb
```

If the user needs to be able to upload multiple files in a single request and they may total more than 10Mb, then you will need to configure `multipart.maxRequestSize` to a higher value:

```
multipart:
    maxFileSize: 10Mb
    maxRequestSize: 100Mb
```

Source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: i added this:     http:
         multipart:
            maxFileSize: 100Mb
            maxRequestSize: 100Mb 
  to the spring section but it did not help.

Comment: @tibi if you're using Sprint Boot 1.4.x check webmaster's answer because this property has changed.

Answer (score 17):

There is some difference when we define the properties in the application.properties and application yaml.

In application.yml :

```
spring:
    http:
      multipart:
       max-file-size: 256KB
       max-request-size: 256KB
```

And in application.propeties :

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=128KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=128KB
```

Note : Spring version 4.3 and Spring boot 1.4

Answer (score 17):

In `spring 2.x` . Options have changed slightly. So the above answers are almost correct but not entirely . In your `application.properties` file , add the following-

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the the solution at Expert Exchange, which worked fine for me.

```java
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("124MB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("124MB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Ref: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28990849/How-to-increase-Spring-boot-Tomcat-max-file-upload-size.html

Answer (score 9):

These properties in spring boot application.properties makes the acceptable file size unlimited -

```
# To prevent maximum upload size limit exception
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=-1
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=-1
```

Answer (score 8):

More specifically, in your `application.yml` configuration file, add the following to the "spring:" section.

```
http:
    multipart:
        max-file-size: 512MB
        max-request-size: 512MB
```

Whitespace is important and you [cannot use tabs for indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Syntax).

Comment: If this is a property that needs to be set in both dev and prod, just adding it to `application.yml` will cause it to cascade to both profiles so you don't need to set it twice.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE` and I had the same issue. None of above solutions are not worked for me. But finally adding following property to `application.properties` was fixed the problem.

```
multipart.max-file-size=10MB
```

Comment: Worked also for Spring Boot v1.2.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 4):

If you get a "connection resets" error, the problem could be in the Tomcat default connector *maxSwallowSize* attribute added from Tomcat 7.0.55 ([ChangeLog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html))

From [Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes)

> **maxSwallowSize**:
>   The maximum number of request body bytes (excluding transfer encoding
>   overhead) that will be swallowed by Tomcat for an aborted upload. An
>   aborted upload is when Tomcat knows that the request body is going to
>   be ignored but the client still sends it. If Tomcat does not swallow
>   the body the client is unlikely to see the response. If not specified
>   the default of 2097152 (2 megabytes) will be used. A value of less
>   than zero indicates that no limit should be enforced.

For Springboot embedded Tomcat declare a TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory

Java 8:

```java
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbedded() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
        if ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)) {
            //-1 for unlimited
            ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
        }
    });
    return tomcat;
}
```

Java 7:

```java
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbedded() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer()  {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            if ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)) {
                //-1 for unlimited
                ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
            }
        }
    });
    return tomcat;
}
```

Or in the Tomcat/conf/server.xml for 5MB

```xml
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8443"
       maxSwallowSize="5242880" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is extremely late to the game, but I wanted to post the additional issue I faced when using mysql, if anyone faces the same issue in future.

As some of the answers mentioned above, setting these in the application.properties will mostly fix the problem

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=16MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=16MB
```

I am setting it to 16 MB, because I am using mysql MEDIUMBLOB datatype to store the file.

But after fixing the application.properties, When uploading a file > 4MB gave the error:
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into test_doc(doc_id, duration_of_doc, doc_version_id, file_name, doc) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Packet for query is too large (6656781 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (6656781 > 4194304). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.

So I ran this command from mysql:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 1024*1024*16;
```

Answer (score 4):

I had used this configuration with **spring-boot 2.5.2** and it works fine:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Look at the official documentation: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Answer (score 3):

Aligned with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50269709/2873538) of Askerali Maruthullathil, this is what is working for me (Spring boot with Spring 5.2.2):

```
@Configuration
public class MultipartRequestFileConfig {

    @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        resolver.setResolveLazily(true);
        resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(83886080);
        resolver.setMaxUploadSize(83886080);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this exception you can take help of VM arguments just as I used in Spring 1.5.8.RELEASE:

```
-Dspring.http.multipart.maxFileSize=70Mb
-Dspring.http.multipart.maxRequestSize=70Mb
```

Comment: VM Arguments can override the values given in application.yml

Answer (score 0):

None of the configuration above worked for me with a Spring application.

Implementing this code in the main *application* class (the one annotated with @SpringBootApplication) did the trick.

```java
@Bean 
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws Exception {
     return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) -> {

              if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {

                  TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                  tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(
                          (connector) -> {
                              connector.setMaxPostSize(10000000);//10MB
                          }
                  );
              }
    };
}
```

You can change the accepted size in the statement:

> connector.setMaxPostSize(10000000);//10MB

Answer (score 0):

For me nothing of previous works (maybe use application with yaml is an issue here), but get ride of that issue using that:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.MultipartConfigFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.util.unit.DataSize;

import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;

@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize(DataSize.ofBytes(512000000L));
        factory.setMaxRequestSize(DataSize.ofBytes(512000000L));
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you request flow through the Netflix Zuul edge service, make sure to update the below properties in both Zuul and your file upload service.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the tomcat max size

```yaml
server:
  tomcat:
    # unlimited
    max-swallow-size: -1
    max-http-form-post-size: -1
```

Answer (score -2):

put this in your `application.yml` file to allow uploads of files up to 900 MB

```
server:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 900000000  #900M
      max-request-size: 900000000
```