# While sending heavy json almost 5MB it will give me java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: spring, api, spring-boot, java

***would like to post a huge JSON object, but when i try i got this error:***

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:162)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:122)
 at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.writeTo(StringEntity.java:169)
 at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:158)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:162)
 at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
 at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
 at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
 at com.os.util.helper.microServiceHelper.AbstractMicroServiceHelper.getResultFromMicroServices(AbstractMicroServiceHelper.java:196)
 at com.os.util.helper.microServiceHelper.IsheetVersionMicroserviceImpl.bulkInsertUpdateIsheetVersion(IsheetVersionMicroserviceImpl.java:75)
 at com.os.gfnactions.isheet.IsheetVersionPutInMicroserviceThread.run(IsheetVersionPutInMicroserviceThread.java:36)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Socket Exception**

When I am sending a large heavy json through HttpClient Post request it will give me a below error.

so how to solve below error i was study all posted question.but doesn't get a proper solution for my error.

FYI : Basically we are use spring boot api at server side. we are call that api from a application which is in java.

can you please anyone help me solve below error??

1) How to send from client side in java ?

2) How to get server side that json in java ?

Comment: I think posting huge text it's not good idea. I propouse you should split this json and apply some pagination for this.

Comment: did you try increasing timeout ?

Comment: @lukassz do you have any other way without split a json because we already split that json in small json actually original json size is almost 50 MB.

Comment: @pvpkiran we never use timeout.how to use timeout??? .how its works??

Comment: As @lukassz said it is not a good idea to send huge files. But stil you can check this to increase timeout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000214/java-http-client-request-with-defined-timeout  you can set different types of timeout

Comment: I too faced the similar problem with my sprint boot app, you might need to increase the max size of the upload file as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540028/how-to-set-the-max-size-of-upload-file

Comment: Instead of sending it as text file, you could send it as binary file as N chunk of P bytes, and use sequence/index (eg: send chunks of file, then one order to rearrange those chunk). That would remove the timeout/limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try increase socket timeout by typing `socket.setSoTimeout(number)`

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)

Posting huge text it's not good idea. You should apply some pagination for this and split eg. every 200kb.

For big json files I recommend BSON http://bsonspec.org/

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason it might happen is because of the request size limitation on the tomcat server. In that case you will need to increase that as mentioned on [How to set the max size of upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540028/how-to-set-the-max-size-of-upload-file)