# How to resolve FileSizeLimitExceededException error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat9

I'm getting error while uploading excel file size is more the 1MB.

```
[org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request;
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException:
 The field files exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.]
```

I tried to fix it by applying the following config changes but none of them help me.

Try with configuration in `application.yml` file :

```
spring:
      http:
         multipart:
             max-file-size:5MB
             max-request-size:5MB
```

And also I've tried the below annotation:

```
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold=1024*1024*10,maxFileSize=1024*1024*10,maxRequestSize=1024*1024*10)
```

And last I made this change:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" maxSwallowSize="-1"   />
```

But nothing does work !

Comment: The property is named `spring.http.multipart.max-file-size`, not `Spring.http.multipart.max-file-size`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the max size of upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540028/how-to-set-the-max-size-of-upload-file)

Comment: please try to clean the project and make sure you have not misspelled it

Answer (score 8):

I tried Alien's solution but it gave deprecated error, hence I want to share new way of solution

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
```

Comment: the question is about how to handle the FileSizeLimitExceededException exception, not how to set the max file size

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your property `S` in Spring is uppercase instead of lowercase.

With spring-boot 1.5.2 you can use the following property in `application.yml`

```
spring:
 http:
  multipart:
   max-file-size: 100MB
   max-request-size: 100MB
```

**Make sure to use spaces and not tab in your yaml file.**

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this typo is only present over copy past of Stackoverflow page. in my application it could be small case only(ie., spring)

Comment: though this is not handling the FileSizeLimitExceededException, just setting the limit.

Comment: how to handle the exception and show to user that message

Answer (score 2):

Try using the below code:

```
spring:
  profiles: development
  servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Include below code in your SpringBootWebApplication class(Main):

For Java 8:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbedded() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
        if ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)) {
            //-1 for unlimited
            ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
        }
    });
    return tomcat;
}
```

for Java 7:

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbedded() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer()  {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            if ((connector.getProtocolHandler() instanceof AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>)) {
                //-1 for unlimited
                ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
            }
        }
    });
    return tomcat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring boot 2.x and above its

Application properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

YAML

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 10MB
```