# How limit max size request in Spring Web Services?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-ws

I have got a Spring Boot 2 application with Spring Web Services and I try to limit max size of incoming requests. I've tried to use the following properties, but it doesn't work.

```
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size
```

Do you know any working solution to limit max size of incoming requests in Spring Boot 2 application with Spring Web Services?
In the Spring Web Services [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.9.RELEASE/reference/#_embedded_http_server_transport) there is information that Spring Web Services provides a transport based on Sun’s JRE 1.6 HTTP server. Maybe it's a problem?

Comment: Spring Boot 2 or 1 ?

Comment: It's Spring Boot 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the max size of upload file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540028/how-to-set-the-max-size-of-upload-file)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Bean with your application and set your required size (Currently 10 MB)

```
// Set maxPostSize of embedded tomcat server to 10 MB (default is 2 MB, not large enough to support file uploads > 1.5 MB)
    @Bean
    EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws Exception {
        return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) -> {
            if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
                tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(
                    (connector) -> {
                        connector.setMaxPostSize(10000000); // 10 MB
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: It's Spring Boot 2 application, so I tried to use TomcatServletWebServerFactory, but it still does not work and big size requests are not filtered out.

`@Component
public class CustomContainer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(final TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> connector.setMaxPostSize(1000000));
    }
}`

Comment: @MateuszZieliński can you try put in springbootapplication class it self ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've decided to create a filter.

```
@Bean
public Filter maxRequestSizeFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) {

        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse,
            final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            final long size = servletRequest.getContentLengthLong();
            if (size > maxRequestSizeInBytes) {
                ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
            } else {
                    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an HTTP POST request that you are using?

Because

- **spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size**
- **spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size**

works perfectly

GET for large requests is not the best idea. If you really need then you can try **server.max-http-header-size**

All 3 parameters verified on tomcat 8.5